# Optimize a Deeply Nested Eloquent Loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How would I take something with a crazy N+1 issue like:

```
        foreach ($serie->categories as $category) {
            foreach ($category->processes as $process) {
                foreach ($process->cards as $card) {
                    foreach ($card->groups as $group) {
                        $group->upload;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And make it into one or two statements?
I'm using Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Tell us what relations you have between these models, as eager loading nested relations here will run 5 queries anyway, so probably you need to do it differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do deeply nested eager loading with:

```
Serie::with('categories.processes.cards.groups')->get();
```

This already loads all processes per category, cards per process, etc.

Look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

If you want a quick way to get all groups, try:

```
$series = Serie::with('categories.processes.cards.groups')->get()->toArray();

$groups = array_pluck($series, 'categories.processes.cards.groups');
```

This returns the attributes for every group in array format. You only need to find a new way to perform the `->upload()` method on the group object.

Comment: I was doing something wrong in my attempt at this.  Thank yoU!